# transaction verification failed on monero-blockchain-import

Tags: blockchain, monerod-commands

I am new to monero. I'm running version:

```
Monero 'Boron Butterfly' (v0.14.0.2-release) on Arch Linux
```

I started with the following steps:

```
wget -c --progress=bar https://downloads.getmonero.org/blockchain.raw
/usr/bin/monero-blockchain-import --data-dir /path/to/monero --input-file blockchain.raw
```

After running for many hours, it failed with this message. I'm showing just the last few lines of output:

```
block 1633270 / 18472752019-06-02 11:15:18.531      7fcc4d902bc0        INFO    global  src/blockchain_db/lmdb/db_lmdb.cpp:615  [batch] DB resize needed
2019-06-02 11:15:58.407     7fcc4d902bc0        INFO    global  src/blockchain_db/lmdb/db_lmdb.cpp:535  LMDB Mapsize increased.  Old: 63571MiB, New: 67151MiB

block 1663990 / 18472752019-06-02 11:22:44.953      7fcc4d902bc0        INFO    global  src/blockchain_db/lmdb/db_lmdb.cpp:615  [batch] DB resize needed
2019-06-02 11:22:48.405     7fcc4d902bc0        INFO    global  src/blockchain_db/lmdb/db_lmdb.cpp:535  LMDB Mapsize increased.  Old: 67151MiB, New: 71675MiB
block 1797110 / 18472752019-06-02 13:17:42.733      7fcc4d902bc0        ERROR   bulletproofs    src/ringct/bulletproofs.cc:1221 Verification failure at step 1
2019-06-02 13:17:42.733     7fcc4d902bc0        ERROR   bcutil  src/blockchain_utilities/blockchain_import.cpp:207      transaction verification failed, tx_id = e32ac43f3371cf76d7a0e9fdd62c1ccd315e5ccd648e356fda69c52d945e6822
2019-06-02 13:17:45.343     7fcc4d902bc0        ERROR   bcutil  src/blockchain_utilities/blockchain_import.cpp:207      transaction verification failed, tx_id = e32ac43f3371cf76d7a0e9fdd62c1ccd315e5ccd648e356fda69c52d945e6822
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a known bug, thought fixed in master, and restarting the import will continue just fine. If it does not, then it's time to report the bug to https://github.com/monero-project/monero